# Intellij not understanding a String method

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

The following is not compiling in intellij:

```
val leader = "_" * 8
val namePlaceholder = " " * 12
```

[image]

Naturally the code is fine in the `repl`:

```
scala>     val leader = "_" * 8
leader: String = ________

scala>     val namePlaceholder = " " * 12
namePlaceholder: String = "            "
```

Providing some "assistance" to Intellij did not have an effect:

e.g.

```
import StringLike._
```

or

```
val leader = "_".*(8)
```

Any ideas how to mollify IJ ?  I am on 2016.2 Ultimate

Comment: Did you really need to show the same error twice?

Comment: Does it build with SBT?

Comment: No problems on 2016.2.3 (Community).  Upgraded to 2.4 and still no issues.

Comment: Assert (scala-sdk version in intellij == scala version of the repl)